# Is it possible to make a command within align* environment?

Tags: macros, amsmath, align

I'm making some math-mode macros, but some of them try to define new commands (to use as variables) within the `align*` math mode. I've isolated the problem to this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        5+5 &= 10\\
        \def\answer{10}\\
        \answer
        \newcommand{\answer}{10}\\
        \answer
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Which fails because neither `\def` nor `\newcommand` work inside `align*`.

Is it possible to make `\def` work inside `align*`? If not, are there other ways to store variable numbers from within the `align*` environment?

Comment: Could you explain why you need this? Because there is a the exam class that can work with hidden answers.

Comment: Each cell in align and in tables are a group of their own so your definition never leaves the cell it was defined in. You need to make it global.

Comment: I'm using `LuaTeX` to make simple calculator functions available, so that `align*` basically becomes a graphing calculator and the formulas generate equations and drawings as you go to speed up note taking. `\answer` would work as expected, recalling the solution of the last line within `align*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They work; you're just not using them properly...

Each of the "cells" inside an `align` makes a group. As such, your use of `\def` and/or `\newcommand` doesn't survive beyond the `&` or `\\`. Inside, using `\gdef` (a `\global\def`) works without problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  5+5 &= 10\\
  \gdef\answer{10}\\
  \answer
  \gdef\answer{10}\\
  \answer
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note that `align` processes its body twice.

Comment: Perfect! I know so little about LaTeX... On the other hand, I figured out how to solve the problem using LuaTex, so... I know just enough to be dangerous, I guess.

Comment: If I use this in my macros (where `\answer` gets redefined a lot) I get the `TeX capacity exceeded` error, do you know why that is happening? I thought I was saving space by reusing a variable.—–Never mind, looks like `\xdef` (`\global\edef`?) is what I need.

Comment: @Ryan: You must have had some recursive definition. `\xdef` is like a `\global\edef` (an expanded global definition).